# SPARQL how to do the log on ordering

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This question is about a *how-to* so it is not about **why-not-working* so I didn't provide you with a minimum data, but if you need, i'm more than happy to do so.

This is my query

```
select  ?item (AVG(?ratingValue) as ?avg) (COUNT(*) as ?count) 
{
    values ?specificUser {bo:ania}
    ?user a rs:User ; rs:hasRated [ rs:hasRatingDate ?ratingDate ; rs:aboutItem ?item ; a rs:Likes ; rs:ratesBy ?ratingValue ] .

    FILTER ( ?ratingDate >= (now() - "P10000D"^^xsd:duration) )
   # FILTER (?user != ?specificUser)
}
group by ?item
```

this is my result

[image]

I don't want to order by `?avg` but i want to order by:

`?avg-(log(?count)+1)`

Any idea please how to do that.

To be honest, I didn't even know how to do the `log` in the first place, because [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-numerics) they don't say there are any logarithm functions to be applied on numeric values

Comment: If your endpoint supports a log function,  you can just add `order by (?avg - log (?count))`. (Note that the +1 doesn't affect the ordering, since it's just a constant.) If the endpoint doesn't support it, then you'd need to approximate it somehow.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm using fuseki, which sounds doesn't support it yet, well I'm trying to order the items based on their **importance**, the average doesn't help here (this is the average of rating), because look at `bo:1984`, it has one rating which is the highest possible (1), but the `bo:animalFarm` has 4 ratings with average `0.92` so logically i should recommend `bo:animalFarm` not `bo:1984` that is why i thought the `log` could give me a correct ordering. do you know please any other way to order that and be applicable to be applied on SPARQL?

Comment: You may multiply `avg` with `count` and then sort descending?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I didn't see that is coming, I'm thinking about it because my senario is more complicated that the showed example. i will update you

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I'm thinking about it, it is not correct to do the multiply because let's say there is an item that has 1000000 ratings so `count` = 1000000, but the average of ratings is `0.3` (so small), while another item has 1000 ratings with average 0.9, do the multiply you get 30000 for the bad item and 900 for the good item, so i will recommend the bad item.

Comment: You'll need to have a precise criteria in mind.  One thing you could do is sort by the average, and then by count, so you'd get highest rating with highest count first, to highest rating with least count, to second highest rating with highest count, to second highest rating with lowest count, and so on.  I don't think that's exactly what you want either, though, based on what you said.

Comment: "so logically i should recommend bo:animalFarm not bo:1984" whether this is logical or not depends on the criteria you want to order with.  It's perfectly logical to recommend 1984 if you say you want highest rating first.  Bit if you want some combination, you'll need to decide what you want to use, and how you want to combine the values.  Say you've got count 2 and value .95 and count 1 and value 1.0. Which wins then? You'll just need to define that first.

Comment: You're right sorry

Comment: While it won't completely answer the question, questions like [Creating an index of quality from multiple variables to enable rank ordering](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/creating-an-index-of-quality-from-multiple-variables-to-enable-rank-ordering) may be helpful here.  (I'm taking a look at the link to posynomials from one the answers now.)  [Multiple-criteria decision analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-criteria_decision_analysis) also looks helpful.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor sort by average and count is wrong in my case because if an item (i1) has 2 ratings with average 1, and another item has 10000000 ratings with average (0.9), i would recommend i1 before i2, and that is wrong because i have 100000 users said i2 is good and just two users says i1 is good so i believe the opinion of more people. for your second commend: *Say you've got count 2 and value .95 and count 1 and value 1.0. Which wins then* it wins the one with 0.95, to understand me more, imagein that the count wasn't just 2, but it was 200000, then you see that  (continue next comment)

Comment: then you see that 0.95 from 200000 users is better than 1 from 1 user, who could be the owner of the item bty :), for your third comment, i am checking the links

Comment: @AniaDavid Yes, the big cases usually are easier to make decisions about, but if you're going to write a formula for this kind of thing, it *will* make decisions about cases like "10 counts of 0.7" and "100 of 0.6"  Which is better in that case?    Do more counts for a rating always make it better than a higher rating with lower counts, or is there some inflection point, where ratings become "bad"?  E.g., if 100 ratings of 0.97 is better than 1 rating of 1.0, is 100 ratings of 0.0 better than 1 rating of 0.03? Seems like the 0.03 should be better, doesn't it?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i see your point, which i was already aware of, and which i have no specific answer, but as you said there should be an inflectin point (i believe that there should be a math model for that, there must be people have similar problems in the past), and also remember that i do a cut edge on the average, i don't accept any average less than 0.8, and i don't accept any item that has got less than 2000 ratings.

Comment: @AniaDavid "remember that i do a cut edge on the average, i don't accept any average less than 0.8, and i don't accept any item that has got less than 2000 ratings. "  Where would I *remember* that from?  It's not mentioned in the question, and in fact the question uses relatively low values (which is probably fine), but you've been talking about examples with counts of 1 vs 100, etc.  If the counts really always are as high as 2000, is there some point at which you can say that there are enough people to have a reasonably standard rating, and you can just look at the average instead?

Comment: Or maybe the variance in the ratings should be taken into account.  After all, lots of items probably have multi-modal distributions (e.g., 75% of people like it and give it a high rating, remaining 25% hate it and give a low rating.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor sorry about the *remember thing*, i didn't mention in the question. * is there some point at which you can say that there are enough people to have a reasonably standard rating* let's say yes (if that solves the problem), i can make that *point* as a variable and keep changing its value each time i do the query,

Comment: You could write a custom function in Jena and use it in Fuseki indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation:

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-function.html

and see the Leviathan Function Library.

The next release (Jena 3.1) supports `math:log` from "XPath/XQuery functions v3"